# Whole computer freezes randomly when playing using Wine

Tags: 11.10, wine, freeze

The problem is that when I play GTA: Vice City or San Andreas, for example, the computer may freeze.
It happens randomly, I can play several times for half an hour a day and don't get the freeze and the next day I can get it easily.
I tried running with the latest updates (OS, video driver and Wine) and without them on older versions of the stuff, but it doesn't matter: I get crashes in each case.

Running Ubuntu 11.10 Oneiric Ocelot, video card [HIS Radeon HD4850](http://www.hisdigital.com/un/product2-30.shtml) 11.12 Catalyst, Wine 1.3.36 now.

In Catalyst everything is set to better performance, Catalyst AI - Advanced.

[image]

In Wine vertex shader is disabled to avoid a game bug (peds were too dark), 'window settings' are all checked, desktop size is 1920x1080 (maximum).
There are two monitors, I'm playing on #1 only, they are set to mirror each other.

The computer seems to be fully hung up: Ctrl+Alt+Backspace or Ctrl+Alt+F1 don't work, but Alt+PrtScr+r,s,e,i,n,u,b combo reboots the computer.

Comment: I have the same problem playing spore with wine. I do this `wine SporeApp.exe -safe` and play with out any problem. But later on when I try to hibernate the computer it freezes. http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=11586013

Comment: This question should instead be filed as a bug report, thanks! [Instructions here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).

Answer (score 1):

My best guess is that the crash is probably graphics related, so you should try to run with another driver (the open-source driver - even though it is slower) to confirm this theory.

Comment: [fglrx] ASIC hang happened

Comment: look for a newer or more stable version of fglrx, a quick google search shows that this bug has been reported - maybe a fix will be forthcoming

Answer (score 0):

In CCC (administrative):
-AntiAliansing set to override application setting, 2x
-Adaptive AntiAliansing set to override application setting, performance
-Antisotropic Filtering set to override application setting, 2x
-Mipmap Detail Level set to High Performance
-Vertical Refresh set to 'Always On'
-Catalyst AI enabled, standard
-Tearfree enabled

In Wine:
(1.3.36)
-Windows 7
-On graphics tab evertthing is checked, 800x600 virtual desktop, vertex shader: hardware, pixel shader enabled
-On audio tab all the devices are set manually

Playing with Skype and Pidgin on, and hasn't had crashes for 2 days of quite active playing the same game.
Graphics driver is still the latest, catalyst 11.12.
Ubuntu 11.10, 64-bit, with the latest updates (+ oneric-proposed).

I guess something changed in CCC helped, you can mark this question as resolved.